# How to print RuntimeVisibleAnnotations in java ASM

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I am new to ASM. I have a class file in which I have runtime visible annotations for methods. I want to parse this class file and select the annotation according to specific criteria. I looked into the documentation of ASM and tried with the visibleAnnotation. I can't seem to print the list of annotations of method which I can see in my class files.

My code is as

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.objectweb.asm.tree.AnnotationNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;

public class ByteCodeParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        InputStream in=new FileInputStream("sample.class");

        ClassReader cr=new ClassReader(in);
        ClassNode classNode=new ClassNode();

        //ClassNode is a ClassVisitor
        cr.accept(classNode, 0);

        //
        Iterator<MethodNode> i = classNode.methods.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
           MethodNode mn = i.next();

           System.out.println(mn.name+ "" + mn.desc);
           System.out.println(mn.visibleAnnotations);

      }

   }

}
```

The output is:

```
<clinit>()V
null
<init>()V
null
MyRandomFunction1()V
[org.objectweb.asm.tree.AnnotationNode@5674cd4d]
MyRandomFunction2()V
[org.objectweb.asm.tree.AnnotationNode@63961c42]
```

My RandomFunction 1 & 2 has annotations but I can't seem to understand [org.objectweb.asm.tree.AnnotationNode@5674cd4d].

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue myself,  I had to iterate over the annotations which I didn't realize initally.

```
if (mn.visibleAnnotations != null) {
            Iterator<AnnotationNode>j=mn.visibleAnnotations.iterator();
            while (j.hasNext()) {
                AnnotationNode an=j.next();
                System.out.println(an.values);

            } 
}
```

Comment: There is no need to write such verbose `Iterator` code for more than ten years now. Just write `if(mn.visibleAnnotations != null) for(AnnotationNode an: mn.visibleAnnotations) System.out.println(an.values);`. But I’d recommend implementing your own `ClassVisitor` which prints annotations right when encountered instead of collecting all information about a class and iterating over the few you are interested in.

Comment: I tried with the for each loop initially, but there was an error with the type mismatch. "Cannot convert from element type object to Annotation node".  that is why i used iterator instead.